# AnimatorSet with setStartDelay call to onAnimationStart

Tags: android, animation, synchronization

I'm using android KitKat and this seems to be not working as expected. I have an AnimatiorSet which should start after some delay but I want to make some action when the animation actually starts (after the delay). It seems that AnimatorSet invokes onAnimationStarted on listeners immediately after calling start().

Sample code below:

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(
     ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(obj, "x", 10),
     ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(obj, "y", 10));
set.setStartDelay(5000);
set.setDuration(1000)

set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
    {
        // do sth
    }
});

set.start();
```

In this case the listener is invoked immediately instead of delayed. To work around this issue I checked if adding the listener to the animators passed into playTogether gives the expected result and it actually does. Is this a bug?

Comment: it may not the answer but for getting what you want you can use TimerTask or Thread.sleep for the delay . Handler is an other approach also

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround for that is:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
    rootView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // todo
        }
    }, set.getStartDelay());
}
```